# PgSQL - How to import database dump only when database completely empty?

Tags: postgresql, ansible, database-backups

The use-case actually to automate this with `ansible`. I want to import database dump **only** when database is completely empty (no tables inside). Of course there's always a way to execute sql statement, but this is last resort, I believe there should be more elegant solution for this.

[`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html) manual doesn't provide this option as far as I see.

Here's how I'm planning to do this with ansible:

```
  - name: db_restore | Receive latest DB backup
    shell: s3cmd --skip-existing get `s3cmd ls s3://{{ aws_bucket }}/ | grep sentry | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'` sql.latest.tgz
    args:
        chdir: /root/
        creates: sql.latest.tgz

  - name: db_restore | Check if file exists
    stat: path=/root/sql.latest.tgz
    register: sql_latest

  - name: db_restore | Restore latest DB backup if backup file found
    shell: PGPASSWORD={{ dbpassword }} tar -xzOf /root/sentry*.tgz db.sql | psql -U{{ dbuser }} -h{{ pgsql_server }} --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on {{ dbname }}
    when: sql_latest.stat.exists
    ignore_errors: True
```

Ideally this should check if DB empty. No ansible module exist for this purpose. Google is also in silence.. Current solution actually also works, this will give error when import will fail, and I can just ignore error, but it's a bit painful to see a false alarm.

Comment: "empty" is a vague term. Even an "empty" database may have a bunch of stored objects defined. How would `pg_restore` determine it's "empty enough"?

Comment: fixed a question :) empty=database without tables. Freshly created

Comment: I wouldn't expect such a key "without tables" is an extra-narrow requirement. The other person would treat an empty database as the one without sequences.

Comment: You have to broad definition of what's being empty do you? `CREATE DATABASE dbname;` now this is what I call empty database.

Comment: and it's not "empty" since now it's filled with what `template0` has defined. Which may have tables and other objects. And depending on `template0` the outcome of `CREATE DATABASE dbname;`may vary widely. That's why I asked your definition of "empty-ness"

Comment: @holms Actually, `CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE template0;`

Comment: @zerkms Unless you specify a template, `template1` is used, and that could have almost anything in it.

Comment: @CraigRinger yep, I was editing my comment in rush and realized I confused the default template name after the edit-timeout has passed.

Comment: @CraigRinger Sure, `template1` could have anything in it, but usually it's left unmodified. If that option would make intuitive sense 99% of the time, the distinction is simply pedantic. In the same way that a lot of applications mention that they "use SSL", and it's implicit that they check the cert given against a bundle of trusted certs. Should a person be able to disable cert verification if they want? Sure. But that doesn't mean the checkbox labeled "use SSL" is ambiguous.

Comment: @ParthianShot I regularly see issues "in the wild" caused by random stuff in `template1`. So it's not an abstract issue. Many people don't realise that `template1` is the default (and really, I wish it was `template0`). Speaking of SSL, `psql` does not validate the server cert by default, which is a horrible default, and one with direct bearing on your comment about "use SSL" ;-)

Comment: @CraigRinger +1 because: (1) I stand corrected, and (2) I had no idea that was the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To regard the database as empty, we must know there nothing has been added from the point of creation. As postgres does not track this (as already mentioned by @Craig Ringer) I recommend a different approach with regards to ansible.

So, just use a handler mechanism like:

```
- name: Create zabbbix postgres DB
  postgresql_db: name="{{zabbix_db_name}}"
  notify:
    - Init zabbix database
```

Comment: the only problem that notify comes in the end of playbook.. because app wont even start without provisioned db. Any way to execute notifications forcefully?

Comment: Unfortunately now I think it is impossible. But suggested for new version as immediate handlers: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10829

Comment: Meantime you may want use "- meta: flush_handlers" to force handlers run (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/0lMtduWbxwU)

Answer (score 5):

There's not really any such thing as "empty" as such; it generally has the built-in types, the default PL/PgSQL language, etc, even if you create from `template0`. If you create from a different template there could be a whole lot more in there.

PostgreSQL doesn't keep a record of the first non-template write to a DB, so you can't say "changed since created" either.

That's why there's no `--if-empty` option to `pg_restore`. It doesn't really make sense.

By far and away the best option is to execute `psql` to query the `information_schema` and determine if there are any tables in the `public` schema. Or, even better, query for the presence of specific tables and types you know will be created by the dump.

e.g.

```
psql -qAt mydbname -c "select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'testtable';"
```

You can then test for zero/nonzero rows returned on stdout. Or wrap it in `SELECT EXISTS(...)` to get a boolean from `psql`. Or use a `DO` block that `ERROR`s if the table exists if you need a zero/nonzero exit status from `psql`.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is hard to tell, if a database is "empty", as explained by others, it is much easier to check, if the database exists, then create and restore in one step. I'm doing it like this:

```
- name: Check my_database database already exists
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  shell: psql -l | grep my_database
  ignore_errors: true
  register: my_database_db_existence
- debug: var=my_database_db_existence

- name: Copy backup of the my-database database
  shell: your-s3-command here
  when: my_database_db_existence | failed

- name: Restore my_database database on first run
  become_user: postgres
  shell: createdb -O my_user my_database && psql -d my_database -f /path/to/my_dump.sql
  when: my_database_db_existence | failed
```

P.S. Also written a [detailed blog post](http://infrastructure-as-code.de/post/156116682947/running-ansible-task-once) explaining each ansible task in the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In my Ansible continuous deployment I prefer don't check empty DB or not. I run container with default properties and create DB if it not exist, after that I restore DB (create schemes, tables and etc):

```yaml
    - hosts: all
      vars:
        database_name: "maindb"
        pg_admin_name: "postgres"
        pg_admin_password: "postgres"
        pghost: "localhost"
        pg_user_name: "vr_user"
        pg_user_password: "ChanGeMe2021"
      tasks:
        - name: Check if database is exist
          community.postgresql.postgresql_info:
            login_host: "{{ pghost }}"
            login_user: "{{ pg_admin_name }}"
            login_password: "{{ pg_admin_password }}"
            filter:
              - "databases"
          register: pg_info
        - name: Create database if not exist
          block:
            - name: Say status 
              ansible.builtin.debug:
                msg: "Database is not exist!"
            - name: Copy dadabase shchema
              ansible.builtin.copy:
                src: "./files/maindb.sql" 
                dest: "/tmp/maindb.sql" 
            - name: Create database
              community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
                login_host: "{{ pghost }}"
                login_user: "{{ pg_admin_name }}"
                login_password: "{{ pg_admin_password }}"
                name: "{{ database_name }}"
                encoding: UTF-8
                # lc_collate: ru_RU.utf8
                # lc_ctype: ru_RU.utf8
            - name: Create role 
              community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
                login_host: "{{ pghost }}"
                login_user: "{{ pg_admin_name }}"
                login_password: "{{ pg_admin_password }}"
                name: "{{ pg_user_name }}"
                password: "{{ pg_user_password }}"
            - name: Restore database
              community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
                login_host: "{{ pghost }}"
                login_user: "{{ pg_admin_name }}"
                login_password: "{{ pg_admin_password }}"
                name: "{{ database_name }}"
                state: restore
                target: "/tmp/maindb.sql"
              register: pg_restore_result
              failed_when: "'ERROR' in pg_restore_result.stderr"
            - name: Print restore result  
              ansible.builtin.debug:
                msg: "{{ pg_restore_result }}"
          rescue:
            - name: Rollback database
              community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
                login_host: "{{ pghost }}"
                login_user: "{{ pg_admin_name }}"
                login_password: "{{ pg_admin_password }}"
                name: "{{ database_name }}"
                state: absent
            - name: Print when errors
              ansible.builtin.debug:
                msg: "Restore failed, because: {{ pg_restore_result.stderr_lines[1] }}"
          when: pg_info.databases[database_name] is not defined
```

This code you can find [here](https://github.com/Shesoff/devops/blob/848787297ed3da69eabc53622ca7b72e420d79f1/ansible/initdb_postgres.yml)